# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'apps'

Tags: python, gspread

I'm trying to connect Google Colabs to Google Spreadsheets with gspread library.

I created my JSON file but got the following error:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'apps'

You will find my code below:

```
import gspread 
from oauth2client.service_account 
import ServiceAccountCredentials
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("JSON-NAME"-"FILE-NAME".apps.googleusercontent.com.json, links)
gc =gspread.authorize(credentials)

links = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: What are you expecting from `"JSON-NAME"-"FILE-NAME".apps`? Assuming you have copied this from somewhere and are supposed to replace those strings with something?

Comment: `"JSON-NAME"-"FILE-NAME".apps.googleusercontent.com.json` must be the path to your json file something like `"path/to/json/file/jsonfile.json"`